# Websocket alternatives in mobile apps?

Tags: websocket, tcp, udp, system, system-design

Typical system design diagrams for back-end services like Uber involves a proxy and web socket server connection to the client.

I'm curious why only web sockets (and long polling) are considered for these modern web designs. If the demand is for a location update service from a mobile app that constantly pushes location updates to the server, why don't people block out a custom tcp or udp connection between the iOS client and the server for example?

Tcp connection is really what websockets uses under the hood, but with a raw TCP connection, you have way more mature libraries that you can leverage (Netty, Kernel-bypass, FPGA)

Udp seems even better since it's stateless and recoverable during disconnections. If it's a one way stream of location updates, it seems to serve the purpose just fine.

Thoughts?

Comment: May be to have single back-end for web and native apps.

Answer (score 1):

The main point of using Websockets is that it plays well with existing firewalls, proxies and other limitations. It is not uncommon that devices are used in restricted networks which only allow access to web and mail. It is also nice that it also provides a message semantic (TCP is only a byte stream) and that support for TLS is nicely integrated too. While "raw" TCP might have less overhead, the actual overhead of Websockets is fairly small. And often the overhead of the non-binary payloads (i.e. JSON, XML) is much higher which makes the additional small overhead of Websockets irrelevant.

Comment: Interesting. Can you use a binary protocol over web sockets if you want to? Is there any reason why you have to stick to JSON or XML?

Comment: @FredWang: One can use binary protocols over web sockets. There is no reason to stick to JSON or XML. But many developers nevertheless do it since they feel more comfortable with these protocols and know how to use the tools and libraries to process these formats.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich There are plenty of reasons to stick with JSON and XML rather than using a binary protocol. JSON and XML are more convenient, require less code and easier to debug. Basically, it'll take less time to develop and maintain. Applying binary protocol is ridiculously difficult. Having to define separate schemas for each API endpoint on both server and client is ridiculous. In my opinion, we should only use binary protocol when bandwidth is a real problem. Otherwise, it's not worth it.